# how to remove stack trace in validation error mongoose - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

how can i remove stack trace in ValidationError when i call validateSync() like this :

```
user.validateSync();
console.log(user.errors);
```

and i get:

```
 email: 
   { ValidatorError: Path `email` is required.
       at MongooseError.ValidatorError (e:\NodeJS\ProjectDemo\Socket\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validator.js:24:11)
       at validate (e:\NodeJS\ProjectDemo\Socket\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:783:13)
       at e:\NodeJS\ProjectDemo\Socket\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:818:9
       at Array.forEach (native)
       at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidateSync (e:\NodeJS\ProjectDemo\Socket\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:796:14)
       at e:\NodeJS\ProjectDemo\Socket\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1479:17
       at Array.forEach (native)
       at model.Document.validateSync (e:\NodeJS\ProjectDemo\Socket\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1463:9)
       at e:\NodeJS\ProjectDemo\Socket\routes\users.js:19:20
       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (e:\NodeJS\ProjectDemo\Socket\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
       at next (e:\NodeJS\ProjectDemo\Socket\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
       at Route.dispatch (e:\NodeJS\ProjectDemo\Socket\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (e:\NodeJS\ProjectDemo\Socket\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

i don't want stack trace validation error. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set you NODE_ENV to production to disable stacktrace, you can do change it as a enviroment variable

`set NODE_ENV=production`

Or if its inconvenient do it in the .js itself as following.

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
```